# How to set Date Format in GXT RowEditing?

Tags: date, gwt, grid, date-format, gxt

Straight to the problem. 
I have a 6-columns grid, one of those 6 fields being a date.
While editing is enabled DateCell is not editable, as intended, but it changes its display format from `"dd/mm/yyyy"`, as stated in `ColumnConfig`, to a non-specified anywhere full date format.

How to resolve this?

Obviously I can't treat dates as strings, as I thought at first, because I'm going to lose all the possible filtering on date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like that?

```
DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

DateField df = new DateField();
df.setPropertyEditor(new DateTimePropertyEditor(dtf));

Cell c = new DateCell(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
grid.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCell(c);

editing.addEditor(df);
```

Hope it will help. It worked for me.

**EDIT:** Set column date format without making cell editable.

You should try that:

```
ColumnConfig<Plant, Date> date = editableGrid.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
rowEditing.addRenderer(date, new AbstractSafeHtmlRenderer<Date>() {
    @Override
    public SafeHtml render(Date object) {
        SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        builder.appendHtmlConstant("<div qtip='" + Format.htmlEncode(object.toString()) + "'>" + df.format(object)
                + "</div>");
        return builder.toSafeHtml();
    }
});
```

Comment: the fact is that my DateCell has to be not editable. 
doing like you suggest makes the DateCell editable :(

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you wanted it to be editable. Give me a sec and I will give you another example if I can find it.

Comment: There is another DateCell class - instead of being an editor, it just renders the value it is given. `com.google.gwt.cell.client.DateCell`

Comment: Tried with renderer, as your suggestion, but DateCell keeps changing format while in editing mode.

Comment: I have updated my EDIT with a new code sample that works (I have tested it with GXT RowEditing Showcase example). In fact, you just have to set a rendered for your cell while editing